# Copy Parallel - Problem

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

Our data is of pipelines and nodes wherein for each feature there is a line and a point node as end points.

So while copying parallel lines, we need to customize the OOTB tool so as to copy specific number of lines and create a node point at end of each line.

In general tool is working fine except for the scenario where it is a 'V' shaped feature i.e any angled feature.

I have attached the data before using our customised copy parallel and after using the tool.

I am working on ArcGIS 9.3.1 ESRI product.

[image: After copy parallel]
[image: Before copy parallel]

Comment: What is your purpose? creating point at the end of the line or both copy and create point?

And Are you working with ILine or IPolyline?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I am working on ArcGIS 9.3.1 ESRI product. I need to create a point feature for end vertices of each line.

Answer (score 2):

If the layer is a feature layer, you can get IPolyline from each IFeature by [IFeature.Shape Property](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeodatabase/IFeature_Shape.htm).

```
IPolyline polyline = feature.Shape as IPolyline;
IPoint fromPoint = polyline.FromPoint;
IPoint toPoint = polyline.ToPoint;
```

Now create a point feature class and add these points as feature to that feature class.

**EDIT**

I am guessing you are working with all features of your feature class. If that is not right, just change the search method as you need:

```
List<IFeature> GetAllFeatures(IFeatureClass ArcFeatureClass)
{
    var featureCursor = ArcFeatureClass.Search(null, false);
    var features = new List<IFeature>();
    Geodatabase.IFeature feature;
    while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
        features.Add(new Feature(feature));
    return features;
}

List<IPoint> GetEndPoints(List<IFeature> features)
{
    var points = new List<IPoint>();
    foreach(var feature in features)
    {
        var polyline = feature.Shape as IPolyline;
        points.Add(polyline.FromPoint);
        points.Add(polyline.ToPoint);
    }
    return points;
}
```

Now create a point feature class. Suppose, name of that feature class is 'pointFeatureClass'. If you need help to create feature class, you can go through [this](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/d27f1291-9583-4847-9e64-a0db4c8181d1.htm).

```
void AddFeatures(List<IPoint> points, IFeatureClass pointFeatureClass)
{
    if (pointFeatureClass == null)
        return;
    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        IFeature feature = pointFeatureClass.CreateFeature();
        feature.Shape = point;

        feature.Store();
    }
}
```

This code will put a point on each end of a polyline. For your figure, it will create 8 points. If you want to customize it, you can put your own logic.

Comment: Hi Emi, Thanks for your response. I have improved my question if you see I have attached screenshots of the problem. Please provide your suggestions for the same.

Comment: @Sheethal, Is there only one polyline and you break it in every turn? Or there are 4 polylines?

Comment: There are 4 polylines.

Comment: @Sheethal does this works for u?

Comment: I need to copy parallel lines to the selected features.

Comment: you can copy the shape by IFeature.ShapeCopy Property -> http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000331000000

Comment: @Sheethal if this answer is helpful, please give it an up vote and if this is your desired answer, then please accept the answer

Comment: @Sheethal What is your actual goal now? finding parallel lines or copying lines?